# How to do client and Server side validation with Redux-Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a weird requirement. I need to do a redux-form validation client side as well as on the server side. I am able to do it on the client side but not sure how can I do for both client and server side. Checked redux-form documentation where it is done either client or server but not for both at once.

Here is the Code

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
  if (!values.username) {
    errors.username = 'Required'
  } else if (values.username.length > 15) {
    errors.username = 'Must be 15 characters or less'
  }
  if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = 'Required'
  } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Invalid email address'
  }
  if (!values.age) {
    errors.age = 'Required'
  } else if (isNaN(Number(values.age))) {
    errors.age = 'Must be a number'
  } else if (Number(values.age) < 18) {
    errors.age = 'Sorry, you must be at least 18 years old'
  }
  return errors
}

const renderField = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  meta: { touched, error, warning }
}) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
      {touched &&
        ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||
          (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
    </div>
  </div>
)

const SyncValidationForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field
        name="username"
        type="text"
        component={renderField}
        label="Username"
      />
      <Field name="email" type="email" component={renderField} label="Email" />
      <Field name="age" type="number" component={renderField} label="Age" />
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
          Submit
        </button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Clear Values
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'syncValidation',
  validate
})(SyncValidationForm)
```

Now onSubmit I have to do an API request and show the errors coming from the server for each field.
Can anyone explain me how can I add sever side validation while I keep client side validation also working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to write server-side code for this. It depends on what language you want to use, but I guess `node.js`  is good to achieve this. So for validating data on the server you should create a nodejs server, and pass your data (that validated already on client-side) then in `node.js` server validate data again however you want.
So in summary, you should start `node.js` which is simple because both react/node.js are almost the same.
Hope it helps you

Comment: Server side code is already there and it returns list of errors with field. Question is how can I show/patch that errors to Redux -Form.

Comment: @PratikN did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Redux-form has a function you can use to throw submissionErrors inside your onSubmit function. https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/submissionerror.md/
This can be done after an asynchronous call.